# Solving $e^{2z}+e^z +1=0$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

Am I doing this right?

$e^{2z}+e^z +1=0$. Let $x=e^z$ so the original equation translates to \begin{align}x^2+x+1=0\end{align}
Using the quadratic formula for real numbers, we get $\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Equating $e^z$ with both values, let $z=r(\cos\theta +i\sin\theta)$ and we have 
\begin{align}
e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)&=\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
e^x=1 \quad \text{and}\quad y&=\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi k\quad k \in \Bbb{Z}\\
x&=0 \quad \text{and} \quad y=\frac{2\pi}{3}\\
\text{Also,} \quad e^x(\cos y+\sin y)&=\cos(\frac{4\pi}{3})+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{3})=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
e^x=1 \quad \text{and}\quad y&=\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi k\quad k \in \Bbb{Z}\\
x&=0 \quad \text{and} \quad y=\frac{4\pi}{3}\\
\end{align}
Therefore, the solutions are this values, again, $\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Your $z=i\frac{2\pi}{3} \text{ or } i\frac{4\pi}{3}$ because you have got $e^z=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$. In general, $z=i\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}+2n\pi\right) \text{ or } i\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+2n\pi \right)$, where $n \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: darn it. of course!

Answer (score 1):

Beware the notations ($x$) clash.
$\color{red}{\text{Suppose there exists }} z \in \mathbb{C} \text{ such that } e^{2z}+e^z+1=0.$
Let $u=e^z$. $$u^2+u+1=0$$Then, $e^z=u$, with $u\in\{e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}},e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}\}$. Then, $\color{red}{\text{necessarily, }}z=i\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}+2n\pi\right) \text{ or } i\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+2n\pi \right)$, with $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$

Conversely, $\color{red}{\text{these}}$ solutions are suitable:$\{z\in\mathbb{C}:e^{2z}+e^z+1=0\}=\{i\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}+2n\pi\right),i\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+2n\pi \right):n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$